# WSO2 - 3.2.0 - Docker - Create an API - Connection Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create a new API from a rest service in WSO2 Publisher and I'm getting an error when I try to validate the endpoint:

[image]

When I go to log it shows the message:

```
[2021-03-30 22:09:54,744] ERROR - ApisApiServiceImpl Error occurred while sending the HEAD request to the given endpoint url:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

If I progress the creation when I try to test I get another error:

```
[2021-03-30 22:15:31,311]  WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2021-03-30 22:15:31,351]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : localhost/127.0.0.1:8888
[2021-03-30 22:15:31,353]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : CpoExecutorAPI--v1.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint with address http://localhost:8888/cpo-executor/dev will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
```

Comment: This could be due a network connectivity issue in your backend service (http://localhost:8888/cpo-executor/dev)

Comment: I can't connect from inside docker to an external address. I tried docker exec -it <container-am-id> /bin/bash curl http://localhost:8888/cpo-executor/dev I got "Connection refused". How can I solve? @RrR-

Comment: In this case localhost might be pointing your docker deamon. Did you try with `<your-ip>:8888/cpo-executor/dev`?

Comment: Yes. Now I receive timeout when I put my ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the certificate issue, another possible cause for this error is network connectivity. Please make sure that there weren't any network issues while invoking the request and the network connectivity was stable. Also, please check whether you can directly connect to the provided endpoint URL and get the responses without any issues.

Comment: Inside a wso2 container I cannot access an API in localhost :(.

Answer (score 0):

```
WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

With the above-mentioned warning, we can suspect there is an issue with certificates.

Therefore, if you have made any recent certificate changes in your environment can you check whether the required certs are available in the API Manager Keystore?